# Pandas' series contains AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

Tags: python, pandas

My data

```
data = [{"content": "1", "title": "chestnut", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
     {"content": "2", "title": "chestnut", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
     {"content": "3", "title": "ches", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
     {"content": "aa", "title": "ap", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
     {"content": "15", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
     {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
     ]
```

Mycode

```
index=[i['content'] for i in data]

s=pd.Series(data,index)
print((s[s.str.get('title').contains('ches',regex=True)]))
```

Error occured

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

I want to achieve this effect, how do I use contains 
contais document:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains.

I want the data to be

```
[
{"content": "1", "title": "chestnut", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
{"content": "2", "title": "chestnut", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
{"content": "3", "title": "ches", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
]
```

Comment: `str.contains`.

Comment: my data is dict  use str.contains, return nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its better to have a structure that is compatible to the data. Use a dataframe.

DataFrame provides better manipulation of columns and rows. Your data is 2 dimensional i.e. it has items and then each item has attribute with values. Hence fitting into a 2D structure like DataFrame and not a 1D structure like Series.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  content     title info        time
0       1  chestnut       1578877014
1       2  chestnut       1579877014
2       3      ches       1582877014
3      aa        ap       1582876014
4      15     apple       1581877014
5      16    banana       1561877014

>>> df[df.title.str.contains('ches')]
  content     title info        time
0       1  chestnut       1578877014
1       2  chestnut       1579877014
2       3      ches       1582877014
```

For series (Not recommended)

```
s[s.apply(lambda x: x.get('title')).str.contains('ches')]
```

Comment: Any reason behind going for series? I wouldn't be using series.

Comment: Updated answer @xin.chen. I did not understand what you meant by leader

Comment: why recommended series,I just came into contact with pandas

Comment: I have added it in answer so that it might be helpful for other people too.